# Create new column with subtotal for first instance of unique value in column, 0 otherwise

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I have a data set that is as follows:

```
  ClientID        Date  Total sales  Cumulative Sales
0        A  01-01-2000          100               300
1        A  01-02-2000          100                 0
2        A  01-03-2000          100                 0
3        B  01-01-2000           50               100
4        B  01-02-2000           50                 0
5        C  01-01-2000           70               210
6        C  01-02-2000           70                 0
7        C  01-03-2000           70                 0
8        D  01-01-2000           20                40
9        D  01-02-2000           20                 0
```

I want to figure out a way to create the `Cumulative Sales` column, that will be the sum of `Total sales` for the first row of each unique `ClientID`, and `0` for the rest.

I figured out the solution in excel by creating a new column R for counting first distinct value and then using the `IF(SUMIF)` function to calculate the sum:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($F$2:$F8, $F8)=1, SUMIF($F$2:$F$1065, R8, $P$2:$P$1065), "0")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) the non-first values based on the [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) IDs:

```
df['Cumulative Sales'] = (df.groupby('Client ID')['Total sales'].transform('sum')
                            .mask(df['Client ID'].duplicated(), 0)
                         )
```

Output:

```
  Client ID        Date  Total sales  Cumulative Sales
0         A  01-01-2000          100               300
1         A  01-02-2000          100                 0
2         A  01-03-2000          100                 0
3         B  01-01-2000           50               100
4         B  01-02-2000           50                 0
5         C  01-01-2000           70               210
6         C  01-02-2000           70                 0
7         C  01-03-2000           70                 0
8         D  01-01-2000           20                40
9         D  01-02-2000           20                 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with set `0` by mask for duplicated values by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and for first values set `sum` by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['Cumulative Sales'] = np.where(df['ClientID'].duplicated(), 
                                  0, 
                                  df.groupby('ClientID')['Total sales'].transform('sum'))
print (df)
  ClientID        Date  Total sales  Cumulative Sales
0        A  01-01-2000          100               300
1        A  01-02-2000          100                 0
2        A  01-03-2000          100                 0
3        B  01-01-2000           50               100
4        B  01-02-2000           50                 0
5        C  01-01-2000           70               210
6        C  01-02-2000           70                 0
7        C  01-03-2000           70                 0
8        D  01-01-2000           20                40
9        D  01-02-2000           20                 0
```